# what's wrong with my code? countconsonant

Tags: python

```
def countConsonant (s):

    """Count consonants.

    'y' and 'Y' are not consonants.

    Params: s (string)
    Returns: (int) #consonants in s (either case)
    """

    # do not use a brute force solution:
    # think of a short elegant solution (mine is 5 lines long);
    # do not use lines longer than 80 characters long

    # INSERT YOUR CODE HERE, replacing 'pass'
    countConsonant = 0
    for index in s:
        if index == 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':
            countConsonant += 1
    return countConsonant 

print (countConsonant ('"Carpe diem", every day.')) # should return 8
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

`==` checks for equality, and that's probably not what you want. You have to use the `in` operator to check membership, and in this case membership of a character in a string. It follows this general syntax:

```
if x in y:
```

Where `x` is the operand or the one being checked if membership is present in `y`. Applying that to this case, replace your `if` statement to this:

```
if index in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':
```

This will then check if the certain character is in the given consonant string. Also, one thing to note, you only check lower case. That means `C` in `Carpe diem` is ignored giving the result of 9. To ignore case try:

```
if index.lower() in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':
```

This will make the string lowercase when checking.

Answer (score 0):

With the statement

`for index in s:`

you are iterating over all the characters in s. So the condition

`if index == 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz':`

ever evaluates to`False` and the function returns 0 in every cases.

To check the membership of a character in a string, you need to use the `in` operator rather than `==`, which checks for the equality of the values.

If your algorithm is case independent, you could either lowercase the input or add all the corresponding uppercase letters to the string `'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz'`. Since `'y'` and `'Y'` are not consonants as per your requirement, you need to remove `y` from the string `'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'`. And your final code is

```
def countConsonant (s):

    """Count consonants.

    'y' and 'Y' are not consonants.

    Params: s (string)
    Returns: (int) #consonants in s (either case)
    """
    countConsonant = 0
    for index in s.lower():
        if index in 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz':
            countConsonant += 1
    return countConsonant 

print (countConsonant ('"Carpe diem", every day.')) # should return 8
```